# XPath Expression: Extract a hidden form field

Tags: forms, xpath, jmeter, hidden

I am working with JMeter and trying to exract a value with xpath from an HTTP-Response.
That value is necessary for further operations and has to be saved in a variable.

I want the value of the field "version", in the Response it Looks like this:

```
<form id="myForm" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Form">
    <input type="hidden" name="someId" value="163"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="version" id="version" value="1"/>
```

The query in the xpath Extractor Looks like this:

```
//form[@name='myForm']//select[@name='version']/@value
```

This query doesn´t return any value and I cannot find out the right Syntax.
I am not sure if the Statement is wrong or something else.

Answer (score 1):

Let's examine your XPath expression.

```
//form             # Give me any <form> element in the document.
[@name='myForm']   # whose name attribute is myForm
//select           # Give me any <select> element under <form>
[@name='version']  # whose name attibute is version.
/@value            # return the value attribute from the <select> element.
```

This means that your XPath expression matches this element and returns the value `1`.

```
<form name="myForm">
   <select name="version" value="1"/>
</form>
```

You should be able to see the problems with your expression from this breakdown.

Comment: I changed the Expression to:   //form[@name='myForm']//input[@type='hidden'][@id='version'][@name='version']/@value still doesn´t do the trick (also with less identifiers)

Answer (score 0):

1. You should use `id` not `name` for "form"
2. You shouldn't use double slash before "input"
3. It should be enough to use just `name` for the input
4. (Optional) If your response is not XHTML-compliant you might need to check `Use Tidy` box

   Summarising all above, XPath expression should look like:

   ```
   //form[@id='myForm']/input[@name='version']/@value
   ```

   Demo:

   [image: XPath Extractor Demo]

   References:

   - [XPath 1.0 Language Reference](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/)
   - [XPath Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_intro.asp)
   - [Using the XPath Extractor in JMeter](https://blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0)